# jquery on click only fires first time

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for a dropdown list of different categories. When the user clicks on one category in the list, the category selector (the one displayed in the dropdown-toggle) should change its title to the one clicked. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nY7zM/5/).

It works the first time the users clicks an item. But when clicking again on a list item nothing happens. Seems that the on click event only fires once, although I used the delegated version of it (which I need, because the DOM might change).

Here's the HTML of the dropdown list:

```
<div class="dropdown inline hide" style="display: block;"> 
  <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
    <span class="current-category">No Category</span><span class="caret"></span>
  </a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu scroll-pane">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="category-selection" href="#">No Category</a></li>
      <li><a class="category-selection" href="#">Category 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="category-selection" href="#">Category 2</a></li>        
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
$("body").on("click", "a.category-selection", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).closest(".dropdown").find(".current-category").html($(this).html());
  $(this).closest(".dropdown-menu").dropdown('hide');

  return false;
});
```

Comment: remove the `return false;` at the end. It is not needed.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/nY7zM/9/

Comment: @PiLHA, please post that as an answer.  jsFiddle might not always be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the drop down, when you click on an open document, it automatically closes the menu. Using the jsfiddle example you gave, removing the last two lines:

```
$(this).closest(".dropdown-menu").dropdown('hide');
return false;
```

allows the code to run multiple times. Removing the "return false" is just good practice because you already negated the click action with e.preventDefault();

Comment: Thanks, that solves it. But why would the last two lines prevent the event from firing again?

Comment: The very last line doesn't prevent it from firing...it has nothing to do with your problem. I'm not 100% familiar with bootstrap, but I believe that since it automatically hides the dropdown menu when you click a link (it runs the dropdown('hide') method), this line throws an error because the function technically already ran and your trying to run it again on a hidden item.  That's my theory, anyway.